# yum repo with gcc kernel-headers on centos

Tags: centos, yum

Error: Package: glibc-headers-2.12-1.80.el6_3.7.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: kernel-headers

im familiar enough to install a package from the default 'repo' (im guessing thats the correct name of the server)

but if a package is not provided in that default repo, how can one add a repo url and even find a trusted url (with that package for the correct os) in the first place?

it also seems that some use the word 'repository' for what i'd call a package.

thnx and apologies for the newb question

Comment: What command are you running? Output of yum repolist? The current versino of glibc-headers is 2.12-1.132 and does not require kernel-headers (not on my machines @least).

Comment: im trying to 'yum install gcc'. kernel-headers is not on the repo. not sure how to get kernel-headers. its an open-logic centos

Answer (score 0):

You should check the excludes on your yum.conf and yum.conf.d, openlogic sets up a bundle of these. I think something like:

```
$ sudo yum --disableexcludes=main install kernel-headers
```

Should do the trick.